# Sequelize Foreign key: snake_case in DB and CamelCase in code. Does it possible?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I use **snake_case** **in** my MySql **DB**. And I use **CamelCase** **in** my **JS code.** 
So my code looks like:

```
sequelize.define('User', {
        'UserId': {
            field: 'user_id',
        },
        'UserName': {
            field: 'user_name',
        },
```

I created foreign key:

```
 classMethods: {
    associate: function (models) {
        User.belongsTo(models.UserRole, {
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'user_role_id',
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does sequelize able to use `user_role_id` in DB and `UserRoleId` in JS code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of `name` and `field` in the `foreignKey` object

```
User.belongsTo(models.UserRole, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'UserRoleId',
        field: 'user_role_id'
    }
});
```